# Turn off visibility with a redirection or something

Tags: codeigniter, visibility, switch-statement

I would like to make a global switch off for my website like when the user click on a button in the admin side of the website, the homepage turns off to public.

How can I figure it out? Maybe with a redirection on a custom page or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion would be extending the default controller and making the __construct() check for this flag (in the database, in a flat file or whatever) and making the __construct() show the view or redirect to the custom page that you wan't to show your visitors.